# What am I doing wrong? The loop runs infinitely....P.S.- I am a newbie

Tags: c, algorithm

Q. You are given NN sticks, where the length of each stick is a positive integer. A cut operation is performed on the sticks such that all of them are reduced by the length of the smallest stick.

Suppose we have six sticks of the following lengths:
5 4 4 2 2 8

Then, in one cut operation we make a cut of length 2 from each of the six sticks. For the next cut operation four sticks are left (of non-zero length), whose lengths are the following: 
3 2 2 6

The above step is repeated until no sticks are left.

Given the length of NN sticks, print the number of sticks that are left before each subsequent cut operations.

Note: For each cut operation, you have to recalcuate the length of smallest sticks (excluding zero-length sticks).

Input Format 
The first line contains a single integer NN. 
The next line contains NN integers: a0, a1,...aN-1 separated by space, where ai represents the length of ith stick.

Output Format 
For each operation, print the number of sticks that are cut, on separate lines.

Constraints 
1 ≤ N ≤ 1000 
1 ≤ ai ≤ 100      (Source-hackerrank)
My code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
int main(){
    int n; 
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int a[n];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    printf("%d\n",n);
    int small;
    int sum;
    sum=0;
    small=a[0];
    int j;
    for(;;)
    {
        int k;
        for(k=1;k<n;k++)
        {
            if(a[k]<small)
                small=a[k];
        }
        for(k=0;k<n;k++)
            a[k]=a[k]-small;
        for(k=0;k<n;k++)
        {
            if(a[k]>0)
                sum=sum+1;      
        }
        if(sum==0)
            break;
        printf("%d\n",sum);
        sum=0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you using a C++ or a C compiler? Please retag accordingly.

Comment: Doesn't matter which compiler. This is C code, not C++.

Comment: You want to run this using a debugger, stepping through the code, inspecting all relevant variables to learn what is really going on.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: If a C++ compiler is used, it is C++ code, but C programming style. Identical syntax does not imply identical semantics. One very carefully had to check if the code relies on such differences.

Comment: You found anything wrong? I know it can be a very silly mistake but I am tired of going through it again and again. @alk

Comment: Do your own homework.

Comment: If "*tired*" have break.

Comment: It isn't. I just like algorithms at which I am miserably failing which you can see. @Nico

Comment: You create `sum` with value of 0. Then you start an infinite loop `for (;;)` then you do some operations (among them `sum ++`) then you say you will `break` off the loop when `sum == 0`... this will never happen

Comment: I'm going to find out what is wrong. Downloading C compiler, wait a little bit. Although, I can assure you that you have some strange patterns like declaring a variable inside a for loop.

Comment: @HackerCracker69 Would be useful if you add comments to your code and help us understand what is your expectations

Comment: What @alk says - debugger.

Comment: @VictorViola: "*some strange patterns like declaring a variable inside a for loop.*" This is perfectly fine, ad common practice since C99.

Comment: @HackerCracker69 well then you will find what is wrong among the previous comments. Also, you should consider taking an introductory course or tutorial or whatever to programming because there are many bad design patterns in your code.

Comment: @SuperPeanut In beginning of the loop i reset the value of sum to 0. The length of all the sticks at one point will be negative integers or 0 and hence in sum they won't be counted and hence sum=0 and loop should break.

Comment: @Nico for example? And yeah I will get better with time and that's why I am here. If I didn't want to do them on my own I can always find answers online, submit them and be done.

Comment: I do not get why you seem to refuse to learn to use a debugger? This essential tool shows you exactly what is going on.

Comment: @alk I am not using a personal machine right now, but you can always suggest me a good environment for coding offline. I have used Codeblocks in the past and have not found it quite efficeint. And this code wasn't that complex so I expected people to help me out.

Comment: It makes much more sense to debug it yourself because then you fully understand what your code is doing. Waiting for people to help you out (and understand what's going on *without* just running a debugger) instead of sitting 2 minutes and following the program's action in a debugger is very inefficient (and also a bit selfish in my opinion). Mentioning Code::Blocks, I hope you took a good look at this: http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Debugging_with_Code::Blocks

Comment: @CherryDT Never felt the need to use a debugger as I am a beginner and mostly have to deal with easy problems. Now that you mention it, I will surely use it. And I'm not selfish, I am lazy.

Comment: Especially as a beginner, you would have the largest benefit from it, because it will not only help you solve the problem, but on the way also greatly increase your understanding of "how things work" and possibly make you also find other issues you previously missed.

Comment: If a C++ compiler is used to compile C code, it is still C code. C code does not magically transform itself into C++ just because a C++ is used to compile it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are basically two mistakes in your logic

First is when you are finding smallest number

```
if(a[k]<small)
            {
            small=a[k];
        }
```

This is wrong as there will some condition arise when a[k] will be 0. So each time when the loop runs small will always be zero. 
See for example

[image: see example]

So it should be replace with

```
if(a[k]<small **&& a[k]!=0**)
            {
            small=a[k];
        }
```

Another problem is when you are calculating sum

```
if(sum==0)
        break;
    printf("%d\n",sum);
    sum=0;
```

Here, a condition will arise when there will be some negative elements, so result may either be 0 or negative so it should be replaced with

```
if(sum==0**||sum<0**)
        break;
    printf("%d\n",sum);
    sum=0;
```

Due to this your code is in infinite loop

[image: See this image also for better explanation]

Comment: Technically probably the right answer, it's just a shame that the TO will probably just accept and use this answer and open a new question for the next problem like this, instead of learning how to debug.

Comment: Also, `sum == 0 || sum < 0` would better be written as `sum <= 0`.

Comment: Yes, for better understanding I used this so that he may know what i editted

Comment: @Swarnveer The constraint is given i.e. a[i]>0. The test cases will always give array elements>0. And my sum counts the number of elements left which are>0. I am not calculating the sum of the elements.

Comment: I know you are not calculating sum, i am asking about the condition that you used when you are using break

Comment: Because I was once in a similar position as yours, but not because I didn't *want* to use a debugger, but just because I had no Internet, was teaching the stuff myself and didn't even know what a debugger was. I would have been incredibly delighted if I would have known about it. And as I mentioned earlier, the collective time and brainpower used by the SO readers to try and find your problem, compared to the effective help it will give you, is in no relation to the debugger option. But you are right that there is no point in discussing this further. I'll just leave this question alone.

Comment: See updated answer, i just uploaded 1 more image. The contraint that you are talking about has a logical mistake 


It will might clear your doubt

Comment: @Swarnveer when all array elements are 0 or negative, sum=0, so it should break. Please see I reset sum to 0 after every iteration. The point is I have to print the number of sticks I have to cut OR in other words the elements which are still positive

Comment: @CherryDT Glad you shared your experience. I will learn how to use one. Cheers!

Comment: @Swarnveer I am guessing finding the smallest element part of the code is screwing everything up. What correction should I make?

Comment: I have another update to make it clear when you are finding smallest change it to 

if(a[k]<small **&& a[k]>0**)
            {
            small=a[k];
        }

and leave second part as it is 

    if(sum==0)
    break;

Comment: both my previous and this new update is correct

Comment: try to solve it in copy with your code and mine, it will be more easier to understand

take n=3

Numbers = 4,5,2

Comment: the best way to debug your code is to use notebook and implement some print statements  in your code to check what is going wrong just as i did in screenshots.

Comment: @Swarnveer I added that condition already. Thanks. It was a silly mistake. I was considering the negative elements while calculating small which is wrong. 
Input-8;1 13 3 8 14 9 4 4  <br/> Output expected-8 7 6 4 3 2 1 <br/> Output I get- 8 7 7 6 4 4 4 4 3 4 4 4 4 2 1